# Use DB object after disposing DbContext in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Can I still use the object retrieved from `DbContext` after disposing the `DbContext` in Entity Framework?

For example:

```
class partial DBUser 
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

DBUser myUser;

using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    myUser = context.Users.First();
}

// does the following code work?
string username = myUser.Username;
```

I guess it can still be used but any fields that are not loaded (lazy-evaluation) before disposing `DbContext` will return nothing. Am I correct?

I know ideally I should assign the username to a variable within the using statement, but I'm just curious...

Comment: Have you tested this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple members it will work, but if you access related members (navigation properties) that aren't eager loaded, you will get an exception that the DbContext has been disposed.

For instance:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; } 
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

Order order = null;
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
   order = context.Orders.Find(orderId);
}

var orderNumber = order.OrderNunber; // Ok.
var customerName = order.Customer.Name; // Not Ok.
```

To get that happy, you'd need to know to eager-load the Customer along with the Order:

```
Order order = null;
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    order = context.Orders
        .Include(x => x.Customer)
        .Single(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
}

var orderNumber = order.OrderNunber; // Ok.
var customerName = order.Customer.Name; // Ok.
```

The caveat there is knowing what related entities you'll need to include. This is also inefficient in that for larger entities and entity graphs where you use `Include`, this is effectively generating a `SELECT * FROM` query /w joins to return all data in the affected tables.

It's generally much more efficient to leverage `Select` to project the entities into the applicable data structure you need. For instance if you just want an OrderNumber for a given OrderID...

```
string orderNumber = null;
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    orderNumber = context.Orders
        .Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId)
        .Select(x => x.OrderNumber)
        .Single();
}
```

Or if you wanted order number and customer name:

```
string orderNumber = null;
string customerName = null;
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var orderDetails = context.Orders
        .Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId)
        .Select(x => new { x.OrderNumber, CustomerName = x.Customer.Name })
        .Single();
   orderNumber = orderDetails.OrderNumber;
   customerName = orderDetails.CustomerName;
}
```

Usually when projecting you will create a ViewModel or DTO class to populate with the `Select` or leverage Automapper's `ProjectTo` method instead of the anonymous type. The benefit here is that the SQL generated will just do a `SELECT o.OrderNumber, c.Name FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Customers c ON ...` statement rather than all columns from the joined tables. When projecting you don't need to eager load related entities. (No `Include` statements)

As a general rule I advise not to ever pass an entity outside of the scope of the DbContext that it was read from. EF does support detaching entities and reattaching them to other DbContexts, but this technique is prone to added complexity and errors, plus ends up loading more information from the DB than you actually need.

Comment: Thanks, it appears to work in the way you described above